# How to Generate 2 dimensional array of NAN in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate a 2 dimensional array (80 rows and 20 columns) of `NAN`, and then fill the first column of it using random numbers of 1,2,or 3.

So, here is my code:

```
import numpy.random as random
def getRowData():
    rowDt = np.eye(80,20)
    rowDt[:] = np.NaN
    rowDt[:,0] = random.choice([1,2,3],80) # Set the first column
    rowDt
```

but when i run my code, it gives me a `None`.

```
print(getRowData())
None
```

i do not think, the output of my function should be `None`.

So, how can i fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is Numpy

Comment: I have added the tag.

Comment: you are not returning anything in your function. So the result is `None`. The last line, `rowDt`, does not do anything.

Comment: BTW your code is returning `None` because you aren't returning anything. write `return rowDt`

Comment: As @P.Camilleri says, the last line should be `return rowDt`. The answer by @yatu is a simpler and clearer way of getting the 2d array.

Comment: So, it does not return the last line by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your error is simply that you are not including a `return` statement in your function. Consider using instead:

```
def getRowData():
    a = np.full((80,20), np.nan)
    a[:,0] = np.random.choice([1,2,3],80)
    return a
```

---

**Output**

```
array([[ 3., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 2., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [ 2., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]])
```

Comment: the problem is also that OP does not return anything in his function

Comment: But, it still has the same problem. i still receive `None`

Comment: Well thats quite obviously because there is no `return` statement.... @P.Camilleri was that your reason to downvote...?

Comment: Well is that is your point, consider removing your downvote, given that I've corrected my answer accordingly, (which I initially missunderstood) and provided an answer that solves the problem @P.Camilleri

Comment: @P.Camilleri taking into account that I've corrected my answer and it clearly helped OP and solved his problem it seems that your donwnvote is clearly unjustified...